# How to fetch all the keywords from the database in Gatsby

Tags: gatsby, strapi, meilisearch

I'm implementing search functionality in my Gatsby project using strapi and meilisearch where I need to fetch all the words from my database using Gatsby GraphiQL. I guess currently gatsby provide this functionality for markdowns only but I want to fetch all the words I have in my database. Is there any way to achieve it?

I have various components, single-types and collection-type in my strapi database so I'm unable to find any way to achieve this expected behaviour.